# @angular-material-components/datetime-picker - '@angular/material/datepicker"' has no exported member 'DateRange'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I'm on angular material 9.2.0. I installed  `@angular-material-components/datetime-picker` for dateTimePicker .

I get this errors when I run `ng build --prod`.

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you change the import to `import {MatDatePickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';` instead of importing DateRange? Typically you need to import the entire module, and this is the correct one inside the Material Docs

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-ngx-mat-datetime-picker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Thank you @JeremyLucas for your response, no doesn't work

Comment: Try manually deleting your `node_modules` folder, `package-lock.json` , and then restarting your code editor, typing `npm install` and trying again

Comment: @AsakkourSoufiane thanks, struggling with this for half an hour now :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a solution for that on github, The latest version 4.x.x supports Angular 10. For Angular 9, you should use the version 2.x by using this command:

`npm i @angular-material-components/datetime-picker@2.0.4 --save`